# Add a customised third party library to Angular2 Project

Tags: angular, npm

I have customised an angular2-tag-input library that I got on GitHub and is available on npm. I now want to include this customised library in my own project. What is the procedure for including it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `npm install <git-link of customised lib>` and then use the library

Comment: Thanks Rahul, don't know if I need to do an additional step but I keep getting the following error when I try to install from my GitHub repo:  Invalid tar header. Maybe the tar is corrupted or it needs to be gunzipped?